# Two panes pointing to the same terminal

Tags: tmux

I have a tmux session with several windows. I also have a "special" terminal. I want this "special" terminal to be shown in all windows. In fact, I'd like to attach several panes to one pts.

One possible solution would be open another instance of tmux inside, but that is not an option as I have many prefixless keybindings which do not allow nested tmux-es.

I know about pipe-pane, but this helps only to mirror the output, and I want to have this terminal fully interactive in all windows.

Is it possible to do so?

I have tmux of version 2.1, but will be happy to update it if needed.